# Can't find the segmentation fault in my code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    struct node* next;
    int value;
}Node;

int findLastNodeValue(Node* head){
     while(head -> next != NULL){
         head = head -> next;
     }
         return head -> value;
}


int main(){
    Node  *node1,node2;
    node1 = (Node   *)malloc(sizeof(Node);
    node2 = NULL;
    node1 -> next = node2;
    findLastNodeValue(node1);
    findLastNodeValue(node2);
    return 0;
}
```

This code giving a segmentation fault. But I cannot find why does it occur. Can you help me with this one.

Comment: What programming language is this? Is it C? Please tag your question with the language in use. To update your question, click on the **"[edit]"** link under the post. Thank you.

Comment: Whoever marked this question for closure: please read what you have selected as a reason to close it. This does provide a minimal working example and can reproduce the problem at hand.

Comment: `Node  *node1,node2;` (hint: `node2` is NOT a pointer -- your compiler should be screaming warnings at you about `node2 = NULL;`)

Comment: @rbaleksandar there are serious problems with this question. First of all, it does not mention compiler diagnostics, which are part of a [mcve]. Then it does not tell *what the program is supposed to do*. There is no attempt in minimization (would crash with only the latter line)

Comment: @rbaleksandar ... and this is 5 months old already, hence we need to think about the usability of this question. Does your answer help the OP - might be, but they ought to have gained the knowledge in those 5 months. Does it help anyone who lands here with google - no. No one can find anything helpful in the question. There is "What is the fault in code" and "This code giving a segmentation fault. But I cannot find why does it occur. Can you help me with this one." and the answer is "dereferencing a null pointer can crash". It is not going to help anyone :(

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Not true at all.People search differently (the keywords they use as input for the given search engine) hence one person may find this while looking for help while not being able to find another similar question due to the words he/she looked for.Also don't forget that while the OP probably already knows how to solve the problem there are far more out there who don't. Closing a question just because it's old goes against the SO community.I can see question here that have been posted 10 years ago and still get upvoted (along with the many, many answers people have added over time).

Comment: I am not voting to close it as it is old. I am voting to close it as lacking the m and possibly c of the [mcve]. I'd do so if this was 5 minutes old.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues with your code:

- You are `malloc`ing `node1` yet you are not setting the value anywhere. This creates undefined behaviour whenever you try to access `value` - you might crash the program or you might get garbage data, which is usually worse since it then leads to other parts of your code acting weird.
- You are not freeing the dynamically allocated memory. While in your case it's not such big of a deal it tells me that you are not familiar with the way dynamic allocation works (my belief is also strengthened by the first bullet point in this list). Whenever you `malloc` something, always `free` it (in C++ you have `new` and `delete`) and (to prevent unexpected behaviour) set the pointer to `NULL`.
- `node2` is not a pointer. The `*` in `Node *node1, node2;` applies only to the first variable. Each consecutive variable also needs a `*` otherwise it will be allocated on the stack.
- By looking at your code it's clear that you want `node2` to be a pointer (otherwise you wouldn't be assigning `NULL` as its value :)). In that case you are trying to access `next` of `node2` but `node2` is initialized to `NULL`:

  ```
  int findLastNodeValue(Node* head){ // You are passing node2, which is NULL
      while(head -> next != NULL){ // Can't access next of a NULL -> code breaks
          head = head -> next;
      }

      return head -> value;
  }
  ```

As a general rule do the following:

- Try using a function that instantiates your node - since this is `C` you don't have a constructor I would suggest to write a function (or several depending on how much functionality you need) that generates a new node. This way you will ensure that at least there is no chance of not initializing a node

  For example:

  ```
  Node* createNode(int value) {
      Node* node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
      if (!node) return NULL; // If malloc fails for some reason
      node -> value = value;
      node -> next = NULL;

      return node;
  }
  ```
- Try using a function that deletes your node - if there is any chance of accessing a deleted reference again, set it to `NULL` and handle the `NULL` value accordingly

  For example:

  ```
  void deleteNode(Node** node) {
      if (!*node) return;

      free(*node);
      *node = NULL;
  }
  ```

  Note that the code above doesn't delete what's reference by `next` since we only want to delete the node we are passing to the function. If you have `previous` (in the case of a double linked list), you will have to first access the `next` node, set its `previous` value to `NULL` and then delete your current node.
- Whenever you pass a pointer, **always** check if that pointer is `NULL` before you do anything with the data that it's supposedly referencing. Combining this with the node creator function from the first point you can be certain that you are not passing some `Node` pointer that has not been initialized properly

Now as to your function in particular I would do the following:

```
int findLastNodeValue(Node* head) {
     if (!head) return -1; // We have a null reference, so there is nothing else to do here; exit accordingly and check the return value to see if the function call has been successful

     while(head -> next != NULL) {
         head = head -> next;
     }

     return head -> value;
}
```

Comment: Ah, so true! LOL There is `*` missing after the `node1,`. :D

Comment: So the reason why I'd flag this for closure as no [mcve] is that essentially is "I've got a null pointer reference" and if it was minimized there were no reason to ask the question anyway.

Comment: That is why it's nice to add a comment. As you can see I also missed the fact that `node2` isn't even a pointer. There is a lot to fix in the code.

Answer (score 1):

findLastNodeValue(node2) is your biggest problem. When you send NULL into findLastNodeValue, the very first thing you try to do is dereference the NULL pointer at the clause (head -> next != NULL).

To resolve this, you can check for and handle the case when head is NULL in your findLastNodeValue function before your while loop.